# Strange behaviour if amount is set to 0.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My form has the following:

```
<%= f.select(:amount, Order::AMOUNT_VALUES, {:blank => false}) %>
```

My model has:

```
  AMOUNT_VALUES = { '$ 0.50' => 0.5, '$ 1' => 1, '$ 2' => 2, '$ 5' => 5, '$ 10' => 10 }
  validate :amount_values_to_be_of_certain_values

  def amount_values_to_be_of_certain_values
    puts self.amount
    unless AMOUNT_VALUES.has_value? self.amount
      errors.add(:amount, 'not a valid field')
    end
  end
```

If I select 0.5 and submit the form. The form complains saying "Amount not a valid field". If I select one of the other values, the form submits fine.

It seems the problem is with a decimal point that starts with 0.

What is wrong here?

Comment: What type of column is amount? and what is the attribute type in ruby?

Comment: could you post a chunk of log with this request? also you might try `self.amount.to_f`

Comment: @Augusto, it's of integer type

Comment: @Bohdan. puts self.award_in_usd.to_f returns 0.0. params returns:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/qVuxBlbLUYqTGW4Q13G3r4XchjCoE72xd+02qVWoQQ=", "order"=>{"title"=>"", "amount"=>"0.5"}}

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer

Comment: What is the result of `puts self.amount` ? Is it `0` ?

Comment: Zabba, yea returns 0. puts self.amount.to_f returns 0.0. The strange thing is, the form submits with params "amount"=>"0.5".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're storing amount in an integer field, then it's going to round any floating point numbers you put into it down. That's why self.amount.to_f is 0.0, because putting 0.5 into an integer field changes it to 0, and 0.to_f is 0.0.